# iOS - SDWebImage Crashes deleting all the images in cache

Tags: ios, swift, caching, sdwebimage, xcode8.2

[image: UPDATED]I was using sdwebimage for caching images for my Facebook feed like view .

But now I get a lot of crashes randomly when I am scrolling the feed. 
It happens when there are not a lot of data.

Crash point:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SDWebImageDownloadStopNotification object:self];
```

Crash Log:

```
Thread_Bad_Access
```

I think it's not taking self so it is show bad access. :( :(

Does anyone know how to get rid of this ? 
I really got no idea but to revert all my hard work.

Comment: Could you update your full crash log?

Comment: Bala updated image

Comment: I think the problem is with `Self`. I would suggest changing `self` to `nil`.

Comment: Many of them face the same issue. Find this link https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1859. If you want solution just file a issue in Git-Hub